# Connect Ubuntu Server 16.04 to Windows 10 using Ethernet cable

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, windows-10, ethernet

### EDIT:

`ipconfig` on Windows:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::49d7:ec19:199f:b968%13
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.185.104
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

### SITUATION:

I was using Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 as my PC's OS for a long time. And there were no problems with Ethernet connection with my server that is running on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

But now I have to use Windows 10 as my OS. I didn't change settings on my server:

`sudo nano /etc/natwork/intrfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interfaces
auto enp4s0f0
iface enp4s0f0 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

### PROBLEM:

When I run `ping 192.168.10.2 -t` in CMD on my PC I get:

```
Pinging 192.168.10.2 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.2:
    Packets: Sent = 5, Received = 0, Lost = 5 (100% loss),
```

So there is no connection, hovewer the Ethernet cable is working:

[image]

### QUESTION:

How to solve this ploblem and why I'm getting this error?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you sure that your computer is on the same subnet?  General failure usually means your Windows configuration is done incorrectly due to MTU or some other manual setup change.

Comment: @ThomasWard it seems that you're right. Windows subnet is `255.255.0.0` and Ubuntu subnet is `255.255.255.0`. So, I just need to change netmask on Ubuntu to `255.255.0.0`?

Comment: Your WIndows OS only has an APIPA address, which will make it not possible to connect to 192.168.10.2. If you do not have a DHCP server on the network, assign a static IP to your windows machine (like 192.168.10.3/255.255.255.0). Make sure the address you assign is not in use by other devices.